# Inflatable pole less tents

Tags: tents

Nemo has some tents that don't use any poles. Instead they let you inflate some air chambers that hold up the tent with their pressure.

Are there other manufacturers doing this?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this isn't an uncommon practice for tent manufacturers nowadays. They're normally family tents, big 6-8 man, but you can get some smaller 2 mans which are inflatable. It's generally for the ease of people car camping with kids, the quicker the tent goes up the better, or car camping in general as you need a pump usually. Some are in combination with the odd pole still, but there are plenty of manufacturers who do this such as:

- Vango
- Airgo
- Freedom
- Trail
- Outwell
- QUECHUA